# Relation between AIC of each predictor variable and final AIC

Tags: data-mining, aic

I ran logistic regression by R. I want to know what relation there is between AIC of each predictor variable and final AIC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In R table AIC of effective variables (A, B, C, D, E, F) are 217.77, 210.38, 213.69, 222.42, 208.95 and 209.81, respectively. Also final AIC is 206.94. what relation between AIC of effective variables and final AIC?

Comment: Please add any relevant information in the question body and not as a comment @user373401

Comment: AIC is a property of a model, not of a predictor, so it's unclear to me what is happening here. Can you please edit your post to include a [Minimal (!) Working (!) Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/452096)?